# Live Broadcasting React-Native Sdk not found

Tags: react-native, agora.io

I am developing app on react native for video calling and live broadcasting. I have found react-native sdk for video calling but unfortunately i did not find any react-native sdk for live broadcasting. Is there any react-native sdk for live broadcasting of Agora? If any one can help me regarding this, i would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform live broadcasting by using the video calling SDK itself.

You can set the role of a user as "broadcaster" or "audience" using the `setClientRole` method.

e.g `RTCEngine.setClientRole(0);` (audience: 0, host: 1)

https://agora-rn-uikit.netlify.com/docs/api/classes/_rtcengine_native_.rtcengine#static-setclientrole